# unable to get get all occurrences of matched regex_substr in single row oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to get specific data from my database column in oracle 11g but my regular expression is returning me only the first occurrence. Any idea how can i get all the occurrences in same row seperated by "|"??

My query:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(
         '"Error:" {user_1@domain.com}<"User_2" {user_2@domain.com};"Error:" {user_3@domain.com}<"User_4" {user_4@domain.com};',
         'Error:[^<]+<'
       ) AS emails
FROM   DUAL;
```

My Output should be:

```
Error:" {user_1@domain.com}< Error:" {user_3@domain.com}<
```

Current output is:

```
Error:" {user_1@domain.com}<
```

For clear understanding, I am attaching dml of insert statement in my table:

```
insert into tests(result) values ('</span></td></tr><tr><td><span class="inputlabel">[14].</span>&nbsp&nbsp<span class="label">ORC|Boston Medical Center|||||||||||||
</span></td></tr><tr><td><span class="inputlabel">[15].</span>&nbsp&nbsp<span class="label">OBR|05-123|LOINC-Lcl-11546-9-1|20050415||||||||||LocalCode: Abscess2||||c|||||
</span></td></tr><tr><td class="errorlabel" nowrap>Error: Report Status Code (ReportStatusCode of type ID) value (c) is invalid Vocabulary code.</td></tr><tr><td class="errorlabel" nowrap>Message rejected.</td></tr><tr><td><span class="inputlabel">[17].</span>&nbsp&nbsp<span class="label">PID||||||||RecCtl_ID|FORTES|AVERY||||||||||||||||||
</span></td></tr><tr><td><span class="inputlabel">[18].</span>&nbsp&nbsp<span class="label">NK1|NK Last Name|NK First Name||||||||||
</span></td></tr><tr><td><span class="inputlabel">[19].</span>&nbsp&nbsp<span class="label">ORC|Boston Medical Center|||||||||||||
</span></td></tr><tr><td><span class="inputlabel">[20].</span>&nbsp&nbsp<span class="label">OBR|05-123|LOINC-Lcl-11546-9-1|20050415||||||||||Local 128477000||||Report_Status_Code 12345678_30|||||
</span></td></tr><tr><td><span class="inputlabel">[21].</span>&nbsp&nbsp<span class="label">OBX|LOINC-Lcl-11546-9-4|SMED-Lcl-78181009-4|||||F|200504231010|BMC
</span></td></tr><tr><td class="inputlabel" nowrap>Processing Results: 3 Messages Accepted, <span class="errorlabel">1 Messages Rejected.</span></td></tr><tr><td class="inputlabel" nowrap>End Time: 2011-08-07 18:47:47.312</td></tr></table>
</span></td></tr><tr><td class="errorlabel" nowrap>Error: Report Status Code (ReportStatusCode of type ID) value (c) is invalid Vocabulary code.</td></tr><tr><td class="errorlabel" nowrap>Message rejected.</td></tr><tr><td><span class="inputlabel">[17].</span>&nbsp&nbsp<span class="label">PID||||||||RecCtl_ID|FORTES|AVERY||||||||||||||||||
')
```

Table Creation:

```
create table TESTS
(
  result CLOB
)
```

Now i want all the error messages from the above HTML i.e. output should be like this:

```
Error: Report Status Code (ReportStatusCode of type ID) value (c) is invalid Vocabulary code Error: Report Status Code (ReportStatusCode of type ID) value (c) is invalid Vocabulary code
```

Right now i am getting only 1 error message.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

If you want multiple substrings, then the right strategy is `regexp_replace()`.  I think this is doing what you specify:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
         '"Error:" {user_1@domain.com}<"User_2" {user_2@domain.com};"Error:" {user_3@domain.com}<"User_4" {user_4@domain.com};',
         '"(Error:[^<]+<)[^;]+;',
         '\1'
       ) AS emails
FROM   DUAL;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=68afc1057b62f3e890d2016c7ff83a46) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: No - I want something like this:
Error:" {user_1@domain.com}< Error:" {user_3@domain.com}<

Comment: @GucciDeveloper . . . I updated the answer.  I'm not sure why I thought it was working the first time.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my edited question? Above query is not working on my sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly good at it, but - see if it helps.

- sample data from line #1 - 4
- `TEMP` CTE splits the string into rows
- final `select` (line #10 onward) aggregates results that contain "Error"

---

```
SQL> select * From v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '"Error:" {user_1@domain.com}<"User_2" {user_2@domain.com};"Error:" {user_3@domain.com}<"User_4" {user_4@domain.com};'
  3     from dual
  4    ),
  5  temp as
  6    (select regexp_substr(col, '[^<;]+', 1, level) val
  7     from test
  8     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '<') + 1
  9    )
 10  select listagg(val, '< ') within group (order by val) result
 11  from temp
 12  where instr(val, 'Error') > 0;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"Error:" {user_1@domain.com}< "Error:" {user_3@domain.com}

SQL>
```

---

With sample data you posted:

```
SQL> set pagesize 100
SQL> set long 10000
SQL>
SQL> with
  2  temp as
  3    (select regexp_substr(result, '[^<;]+', 1, level) val
  4     from tests
  5     connect by level <= regexp_count(result, '<') + 1
  6    )
  7  select replace(val, 'td class="errorlabel" nowrap>', '') result
  8  from temp
  9  where instr(val, 'Error') > 0;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Report Status Code (ReportStatusCode of type ID) value (c) is invalid Voc
abulary code.

Error: Report Status Code (ReportStatusCode of type ID) value (c) is invalid Voc
abulary code.


SQL>
```

Comment: Actually my data is coming from the column table where i can't create a temp table like this.

Comment: If you posted CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, I wouldn't have to create a test case by myself. Besides, I clearly said that the first several lines represent *sample data*. What do you not understand about it? Code you might need begins at line #5.

Comment: Oh, yes, it is. See my updated SQL*Plus output which shows database version. Which means that you did something wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please have a look at my sample data and table creation script - May be we need to change something else as well.

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more code into the answer. I removed LISTAGG (as your result contains two rows (not concatenated values in the same row). Have a look, please.

Comment: What will happen if i have multiple rows in my table? Will it work? Also i want it in select statement without creating any temp table - is that possible?

Comment: Multiple rows will work as well, with a modified code (because - the one you see now - will produce duplicates). My SELECT isn't creating any TEMP tables. This is just a WITH factoring clause, nothing is ever created in database itself.

Comment: But, it is here, in both of my examples ... Don't you see it? Line #1. More examples online, e.g. https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause

Comment: I need all the occurrences in one row - not in multiple rows - Above query is returning me multiple rows:

Error: Report Status Code (ReportStatusCode of type ID) value (c) is invalid Voc
abulary code. Error: Report Status Code (ReportStatusCode of type ID) value (c) is invalid Voc
abulary code.

Comment: So put LISTAGG back; example that was valid until a minute ago is now changed, and I'm kind of getting tired of going back and forth with it. Best of luck!